# I can't get the aperture to stay at f/4 and shutter speed at 1/1000 in manual mode on a sony a6000

Tags: aperture, shutter, manual-mode

When I set the aperture and shutter speed on my a6000 in manual mode the aperture always changes when I take the photo.  I am using a sony 24-240mm lens f/3.5-6.3.  It does the same in aperture mode.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What focal length are you set at? You might be too far zoomed out to be allowed to shoot at f4.0. what aperture are you getting?

Comment: To expand on @thebtm comment, note that for a zoom lens, the low f-number refers to the widest aperture when zoomed out, and the high f-number to the widest aperture when zoomed in.  So at e.g. 240mm your lens has a widest aperture of f6.3 ( and f4 is not possible ).

Comment: The usual cause is that you have previously selected Bracketing mode, but have not turned it off.

Comment: I think it is the focal length that is the issue.  I need to use a faster lens but I don't have the funds for a faster lens.

Comment: The question should be edited to add the missing information, e.g., "the aperture changes *when I change the focal length*".

Answer (score 3):

Your Sony 24-240mm f/3.5-6.3 lens is not capable of opening up to f/4 through out its entire focal length range. By the time you zoom all the way to 240mm, the widest possible aperture is f/6.3. Your camera senses that and compensates accordingly.

For more about variable aperture vs. constant aperture zoom lenses, please see:
[How do zoom lenses restrict their widest aperture at the telephoto end?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72606/how-do-zoom-lenses-restrict-their-widest-aperture-at-the-telephoto-end)
[Why does my aperture setting change as I zoom on my DSLR kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/why-does-my-aperture-setting-change-as-i-zoom-on-my-dslr-kit-lens)
[Why do zoom lenses and compact cameras have varied maximum aperture across the zoom range?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13918/why-do-zoom-lenses-and-compact-cameras-have-varied-maximum-aperture-across-the-z)